# Sort Wrappers In JSON?

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

```
public with sharing class TableData {

    public String Id { get; set; } // hash modified 
    public Decimal duration { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String owner { get; set; }
    public String type { get; set; }
    public Decimal timeAllocated { get; set; }
    public String dueDate { get; set; }
    public String status { get; set; }



        public TableData(String id, Decimal duration, String description, String name, String owner, String type,
                            Decimal timeAllocated, String dueDate, String status) {

            this.id = id; // hash modified
            this.duration = duration;
            this.description = description;
            this.name = name;
            this.owner = owner;
            this.type = type;
            this.timeAllocated = timeAllocated;
            this.dueDate = dueDate;
            this.status = status;

        }

}
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54683/json-getting-sorted-when-serialize-the-wrapper-class-object - What are you trying to sort by? Are you trying to sort the JSON or the wrapper. Please included details in the question and not in comments

Answer (score 1):

You would sort them before serialization. That is the raison d'être for the `Comparable` interface. If, for instance, you wanted to sort by `dueDate` it would look something like:

```
class MyWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Date dueDate { get; private set; }
    // other properties
    public MyWrapper(...)
    {
        // constructor
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        MyWrapper that = (MyWrapper)instance;

        // nulls last
        if (that.dueDate == null) return 1;
        if (this.dueDate == null) return -1;

        // descending
        return (this.dueDate > that.dueDate) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public static String serializeSorted(List<MyWrapper> input)
    {
        // you could add a convenience method which combines steps
        input.sort();
        return JSON.serialize(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out what i was trying to say lol. The properties within the wrapper are sorted automatically and cannot be ordered with serialize. The order of the  objects themselves is retained if the collection is an ordered collection

Comment: @Eric Ah, right, they're serialized in the order they're declared?

Comment: I do not believe so. They are sorted by the JSON in Alpha  (reverse) order. At least in the few quick anon examples I just did. By no means concrete though. I wonder if that is what the OP was asking about given the words "json key" in the comments (since deleted)